# PHP is_rss($url)?

Tags: php, rss

Is there a way through PHP where I can either with the URL, or `$string=file_get_contents($url)` where I could find out if a given URL is an RSS feed?

I would also like to be able to handle [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com) feeds as a potential issue feed type...

I'm looking to try to automate the discovery of these feeds - (I don't know if this type of thing exists - an example to a reference would be extremely helpful :) based on WordPress and Blogger standards.

Comment: Do you want specifically FeedBurner feeds, or ATOM as well?

Comment: I have a basic RSS Parser already working I'm looking to automate an RSS discovery system of sorts (using CodeIgniter)

Comment: Sorry, with my previous comment, I meant specifically *RSS*, or ATOM as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use excellent [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) library fot that (handles rss, atom, Feedburner) to take the task seriously:

```
// load the simplepie class
require 'simplepie.php';
$feed = new simpepie;

$feed->set_feed_url('your url here');

$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location('cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);

$feed->init();

//let simplepie handle the content type (atom, RSS...)
$feed->handle_content_type();

if ($feed->error)
{
   // not a valid rss feed / url
   echo '<div class="box error">' . $feed->error . '</div>';
}
else
{
  // proceed
}
```

Comment: I'm already using a CodeIgniter based Parser - either way, this seems like a problem waiting to happen - not validating that it is in fact an RSS feed before I try and parse it?

Comment: @Wallter: See if CI's lib supports any such function, normally that should be handled by lib just as simplepie, you will need to look the docs of lib you are using. Other option is to use simplepie, you should be able to incorporate that inside CI.

Answer (score 1):

A barebones unreliable test:

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($string, '<rss') !== FALSE)) {
   ... yes, it's probably rss
}
```

A more complicated version would be to load the XML string (assuming it does look like xml) into an XML validator and see if it conforms to the RSS DTD. More work, but also far more reliable.